# About semantic versioning with Harpy

Tags: ios, semantic-versioning

I have 2.0.3 version of my app in the App Store.  Now I want to send 2.0.4 version. But while debugging, Harpy always asks to update to 2.0.3. Where am I wrong? What should be the next version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harpy checks the current App Store version of your app in the App Store. To check and make sure your app is working, just change the current version of your app in Xcode to 2.0.2 and rebuild your project. When relaunching, you should display an alert for v2.0.3, which means it works. Since it works, you can change it back to 2.0.4 before submitting your app the the store.